# Does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, macos, opencv

I am trying to insert OpenCV libraries in Eclipse. I am using mac osX. After downloading the libraries, I tried to follow the configuration from [this](http://sumitkumariit.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-install-opencv-for-java-on-mac.html) tutorial.

I installed Cmake in my terminal, but after trying to use

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++ -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -D WITH_CUDA=ON ..
```

I got a message says "does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt" in the directory of openCV.

How can I solve this? Is there another way to configure OpenCV in mac Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, resolved by using the below command

Goto Build directory

```
 Try with cmake .. your command
```

Answer (score 1):

This option of cmake lets you generate Unix traditional makefiles from CMake project files (known as CMakeLists.txt). You cannot do it with cmake project files. But relax - it is easy, though you have to detect CUDA in your project. [Sample for you](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/examples.html). [And another one](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/How_to_create_a_ProjectConfig.cmake_file).